# RunTime Error in Flutter: Cannot copy from a TensorFlowLite tensor (Identity) with shape [1, 25200, 6] to a Java object with shape [1, 20, 20, 30]

Tags: flutter, tflite

```
loadModel() async {
    res = await Tflite.loadModel(
        model: "assets/mymodel.tflite",
        labels: "assets/mylabels.txt");
} // Here I am loading my model

// This is where I using tflite to detect object
Tflite.detectObjectOnFrame(
     bytesList: img.planes.map((plane) {
        return plane.bytes.;
     }).toList(),
     model: widget.model == mymodel ? "YOLO" : "SSDMobileNet",
     imageHeight: img.height,
     imageWidth: img.width,
     imageMean: widget.model == mymodel ? 0 : 127.5,
     imageStd: widget.model == mymodel ? 255.0 : 127.5,
     numResultsPerClass: 1,
     threshold: widget.model == mymodel ? 0.2 : 0.4,
     ).then((recognitions) {
     int endTime = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
     print("Detection took ${endTime - startTime}");

     widget.setRecognitions(recognitions!, img.height, img.width);

     isDetecting = false;
});
```

Getting error somewhere here in the code snippet given above.
I am using tflite library in flutter for single class object detection

Here is my error

```
 Cannot copy from a TensorFlowLite tensor (Identity) with shape [1, 25200, 6] to a Java object with shape [1, 20, 20, 30]
```